# Problem mounting USB Mobile Broadband dongle in Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: wireless, 13.04, usb, mount, mobile-broadband

I have been using Ubuntu 13.04 since last two months and I have problem mounting my USB dongle. I have Lenovo G-580 series laptop. It has 3 USB ports which are 3.0. When I attach dongle to one of the three USB ports the device gets mounted immediately but in the other two ports I have to reboot the OS while the dongle is attached to the laptop in order to mount it and connect to the internet. My dongle is of ZTE. I don't get what is going wrong.

Answer (score 1):

If you are facing a problem that your computer doesn’t recognize the device then run the command below:

```
sudo apt-get install usb-modeswitch usb-modeswitch-data
```

Comment: Can you tell me what does this command do?

Comment: Running the above command tells me following:       usb-modeswitch is already the newest version.
usb-modeswitch-data is already the newest version.